# Any good current cross-platform reference for UNIX compiler/linker options?

Tags: c, unix, compiler-construction, linker

I have used this [summary reference](http://www.fortran-2000.com/ArnaudRecipes/sharedlib.html) for years but it is beginning to show its age.  If you have any you might suggest as more current I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is it objectionable to put c and C++ in the tags to get more traffic?

Comment: No, but perhaps tagging linker and/or ld would be wise...

Comment: Which reference does this tag refer too?

Comment: Maybe it's time that somebody maintained a more recent list...Or is there a good reason not to?

Comment: I was hoping someone had a newer reference... I will build my own I think is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some resources that leap to mind:

- [GCC manuals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/): Manuals for GCC at various versions.
- [GNU binutils](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/): Where the real documentation for ld lives.
- [Predef project](http://predef.sourceforge.net/): C/C++ predefined macros for *many* platforms, targets, and compilers.
- [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html): Sometimes you really do want to know what `$<` was intended to mean...

In my experience, you won't find a lot of detail about the cross platform issues at any one of those places, though. I've soaked up a lot of it over the years, but haven't tried to codify that knowledge in any useful form.

I would imagine that any of the cross-platform build tools have to include a fair amount of that kind of knowledge, even if it is tied up in their sources or in their developer/internals documentation. You could try delving into [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), for instance, which tries to know how to create Makefiles for *nix platforms as well as Visual Studio projects at various rev levels for Windows platforms.

Comment: gcc isn't really the defecto standard because of the vendor support for the other compilers.  I was hoping not to recreate something that exists.  I have contacted the author of the link for his permission to modify and distribute the one that is becoming aged.

Comment: I know gcc isn't a standard per se, but it is used on a variety of platforms. GNU ld has features that originate in a *lot* of other *nix variants, but its manual may not explicitly document what came from where. GNU make's manual does have a section talking about what predecessor inspired which feature for many of its features, though. The predef people are doing what you want, but just for the C preprocessor.

Comment: I think GCC and Visual Studio are basically the standards. Very few people use anything else.

Comment: In fairness, in the embedded world there are a large number of other compilers you will see, including ARM's, GreenHills, Kiel, IAR, Hitachi, and DiabData to name a few I've (mostly) personally used on projects for paying customers. There are a lot more than that out there. Although the number of GCC ports is growing and taking some market from the named compilers since about $5K per seat is a lot more than $0 as a capital outlay.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a community wiki entry on SO where you create the table of options.

You could start by extracting the (still up to date) information from your link and then let the users of SO that know other compilers expand it to cover more and more.?

Comment: Is this an appropriate use of this medium?  Is there a more wiki type location than this board?